# Converting Document Library Fields to a Content Type

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, document-library, content-type

so I have one heavily customized SharePoint Document Library with lots of extra fields.  I'm wondering if anyone has figured out an easy way to lift those fields into a Content Type while preserving the underlying data, that which I can use those custom fields elsewhere (and use that new content type).  This been attempted at all?  This is for SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can user PowerShell command to add the existing list column to content type in the document library. Run SharePoint 2010 Management Shell as administrator, then copy the PowerShell command below to change the relevant site URL, library name, column name, content type name and paste it:

```
$web = get-spweb "http://spsitename/" 
$list = $web.Lists["DocumentLibraryName"] 
$field=$list.Fields["columnname"]
$fieldlink=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink $field
foreach($ctype in $list.ContentTypes)
{
  if($ctype.Name -eq "contenttypename")
  { 
     $ctype.FieldLinks.Add($fieldlink)
     $ctype.Update()
     $list.Update()
  }
}
```